# Integrating two vi in Labview

Tags: boolean, tcp, labview

I am trying to combine two different VI in labview, and am not sure where to start. I am at a beginner level, and I tried copy and pasting the block diagram from one VI into the block diagram of another. I don't know where to go from there; the controls for the second diagram don't show up after copy pasting it, and I couldn't put the whole thing into a subvi since it has more than 28 connectors. I don't think copy pasting it will work, but I was wondering if anyone knew where to start.

Comment: The controls should show up after copy pasting, although they might sometimes be on another part of the screen (so scroll around to be certain). Can you show the block diagrams of the two VIs you try to merge? And the resulting block diagram. Your described method should work with some refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [SubVIs](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7593/en/)?

"After you create a VI, you can use it on the Block Diagram of another VI."